# Google Maps JavaScript API won't display markers from KML exported from My Maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, kml

I have a map on Google My Maps that I want to display using the Google Maps JavaScript API; this is so that I can easily combine multiple maps into one and create paths/markers without having to do it programmatically.

Here is the test map that I'm using.  It's a cruddy map but I expect both the path and the marker to show up in my JavaScript.

https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=z_Tk3EyXNpN8.k743LUvJRr1U&usp=sharing

And here's the JavaScript:
http://jsfiddle.net/gB2YD/66/

What happens is the path I drew displays just fine, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the marker(s) to actually display.

```
<title>Google Maps API v3 : KML Layer</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
</script>

<body onload="display_kmlmap()">

<div id="map_canvas" style="width:500px; height:400px; float:left">
</div>
</body>
```

...

```
function display_kmlmap()
{
    // https://www.google.com/maps/d/edit?mid=z_Tk3EyXNpN8.k743LUvJRr1U&usp=sharing
    var map_options = { };  
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),map_options);

    var kmlUrl = 'https://rawgit.com/Ravenstine/a3b18c71942a812b5b11/raw/dafd404a0410bfbc7c4ef77ef1c6437b313e8cf0/testmap.kml';
   var kmlOptions = { map: map};

    // Create the kmlLayer - and you are done
    var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer(kmlUrl, kmlOptions);
}
```

What's strange is I could swear that the markers were appearing just fine a month ago when I first attempted to do this with a proof of concept.

Comment: i am getting a 404 for the URL inside your xml in the kmlUrl,http://mapsengine.google.com/map/kml?forcekml=1&amp;mid=z_Tk3EyXNpN8.k743LUvJRr1U

Comment: @sajanyamaha I noticed that too, though that would appear to be normal behavior(though I'm not quite sure why).  Somehow, the JavaScript API is sending a request to that URL in a way that is allowing it to retrieve enough KML to display the path.  I don't know how else it would get that data.  The way I created that KML file was by going to the first link in my question, click the share icon, choose "Download KML", and check both checkboxes.  Though I have the same problem no matter which of those settings I choose.

Comment: Looks like [Issue 8551 in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8551)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be a bug.

When I remove the `<color/>` from

`Style#icon-503-DB4436-nodesc-normal>IconStyle` I see the marker.

According to the documentation `<color/>` isn't supported at all for `<IconStyle/>` and will be ignored, so it shouldn't affect the rendering.

Related: [Issue 8551 in the issue tracker](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8551)

Comment: If that's the case, I might be kind of screwed because I need to use the linked map so that the JavaScript map will reflect changes I make to a Google My Maps map.  I'm not sure I can write a proxy to edit the KML because their networking seems to obfuscate it.

Comment: It's not obfuscated, it's compressed, you must unpack the archive(kmz), it contains a file `doc.kml` . However, I've submitted a bug-report: https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8551&thanks=8551&ts=1441149691

Comment: Thanks for this, by the way.  I might not have figured this out on my own.  What my client needs is a map that combines their My Maps map with another KML source that has their location history, so they have to be able to use My Maps and have their changes update on the combined map.  Since I don't have time to figure out how to deflate a zip and parse through a KML on the client side, I just wrote a proxy in Ruby that strips out those color tags.