# Google Maps Web API - KML IconStyle color doesn't work

Tags: javascript, api, google-maps, kml

I have a problem with KML and Google Maps Web API.
If I use color tag into IconStyle tag the markers doesn't shows on maps.
It's shows on map if I remove color tag.
I'm sure that the KML worked correctly until 2-3 months ago.

This is my KML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>MAP</name>
        <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
        <Folder>
            <name>MAP</name>
            <Placemark>
                <styleUrl>#icon-961-62AF44</styleUrl>
                <name>BLA BLA BLA</name>
                <description><![CDATA[DESCRIPTION BLA BLA BLA]]></description>
                <Point>
                    <coordinates>12.429284000000052,41.899191,0.0</coordinates>
                </Point>
            </Placemark>
    </Folder>
    <Style id='icon-961-62AF44'>
        <IconStyle>
            <color>ff44AF62</color>
            <scale>1.1</scale>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/961-wht-square-blank.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
    </Style>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

This is my javascript:

```
   <script>
      var map;

      function initialize() {
         var mapOptions = {
           center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.7,12.6),
           zoom: 9
         };
         map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
         var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://test.com/test.kml', {preserveViewport: true});
         ctaLayer.setMap(map);
      }

      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
   </script>
```

Some advise?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in the Google Maps Javascript API v3.

[8551: Bug: KmlLayer-Placemarks with color different to ffFFFFFF will not be displayed](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8551)

> What steps will reproduce the problem?
>
> 1. Create a KML with a Point and apply an IconStyle with a color-value different to ffFFFFFF
> 2. use the KML to create a KmlLayer
>
> According to the documentation in KmlLayers color isn't supported at all for IconStyle and should be ignored(and therefore shouldn't affect the Layer in any manner).
>
> Of course it would be possible to simply remove the color, but when you use KML exported from other applications this is not always an option.
>
> Especially I mean My Maps, where it's not possible to use Symbols(except white symbols) when you want to use the exported KML in a KmlLayer
>
> related SO-question: [Google Maps JavaScript API won't display markers from KML exported from My Maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32323674/459897)

---

> Thanks for reporting it. We've filed it internally and will prioritize accordingly.
>
> Status: Accepted
>
> Labels: Internal-24115271