# Feature points not loaded from Google Maps KML

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml

I am using Google's Javascript API for Google Maps to plot points on a map. The points will then be clickable and trigger other events on a web page (this is why I am using the API, and not just an iframe).

Currently, I am loading in a KML file which has a network link pointing to [this](https://www.google.com/maps/d/u/0/view?mid=zS57AG80cJ74.kthThxU7xjz0) Google map (really, the link just points to a current version of the KML file for the map).

I can tell that the KML file is loaded, because the embedded map resizes to fit around the area that the feature points would occupy. But the feature points themselves do not load on the page. I have a JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xyk5bkr8/3/), or if that annoys you, the code is below. This is such a minimal example that I can't see how it could possibly be failing, after reading the Google Maps API guide on creating a map with a KML layer.

HTML:

```
<div id="map">
    Loading Google Map..
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#map {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
}
```

Javascript:

```
gmap = new google.maps.Map( document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
}); 

sites_layer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://cleanwater.goshen.edu/kml/ccwp.kml',
    map: gmap
}); 

sites_layer.setMap(gmap);
```

The last line of the JavaScript doesn't actually change anything - I'm just leaving it in to show that I tried this and it didn't work.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Different duplicate: [Google Maps JavaScript API won't display markers from KML exported from My Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323674/google-maps-javascript-api-wont-display-markers-from-kml-exported-from-my-maps/)

Comment: Issue on the issue tracker: [Issue 8551: Bug: KmlLayer-Placemarks with color different to ffFFFFFF will not be displayed](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8551)

Comment: Thank you so much! Well, I can use white as a workaround for now. Wow, that is kind of a huge bug... I'm surprised they haven't been able to fix it yet.