# How to export google maps Markers and add them to another map via maps API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a saved map in google maps and there is a layer with 3 markers. A red , a blue and a green one.

i exported the markers in kml and kmz format.

Then i created a map in my website and i added the kml as described in maps api v3.

```
      function initMap() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 12,
        center: {lat: 37.06, lng: -95.68}
      });

      var kmlLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
        url: '<i have the url of my kml file here>',
        suppressInfoWindows: true,
        map: map
      });
}

<script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<my api key here>&signed_in=true&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

It works and i can see the markers on the map all in white color. So the problem is that they don't have a color although it is defined in the kml (i can see color codes as iconStyle if i open the kml with notepad)

How can i export markers and their color from a saved google map and add them in another map with js api? I dont want to embed the whole map because i applied custom style to the map (hidden country name labels).

Is it possible with kml or kmz? Should i choose another method?

My KML file:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'>
    <Document>
        <name>Untitled layer</name>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Point 2</name>
            <styleUrl>#icon-503-009D57-nodesc</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>22.467041,39.436193,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Point 2</name>
            <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436-nodesc</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>21.9836426,39.1556224,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <name>Point 3</name>
            <styleUrl>#icon-503-FAD199-nodesc</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
            </ExtendedData>
            <Point>
                <coordinates>22.7801514,38.5911138,0.0</coordinates>
            </Point>
        </Placemark>
        <Style id='icon-503-009D57-nodesc-normal'>
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff579D00</color>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>0.0</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id='icon-503-009D57-nodesc-highlight'>
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff579D00</color>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id='icon-503-009D57-nodesc'>
            <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-009D57-nodesc-normal</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
            <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-009D57-nodesc-highlight</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
        </StyleMap>
        <Style id='icon-503-DB4436-nodesc-normal'>
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff3644DB</color>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>0.0</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id='icon-503-DB4436-nodesc-highlight'>
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff3644DB</color>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id='icon-503-DB4436-nodesc'>
            <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436-nodesc-normal</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
            <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-DB4436-nodesc-highlight</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
        </StyleMap>
        <Style id='icon-503-FAD199-nodesc-normal'>
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff99D1FA</color>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>0.0</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
        <Style id='icon-503-FAD199-nodesc-highlight'>
            <IconStyle>
                <color>ff99D1FA</color>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
                <Icon>
                    <href>http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png</href>
                </Icon>
                <hotSpot x='16' y='31' xunits='pixels' yunits='insetPixels'>
                </hotSpot>
            </IconStyle>
            <LabelStyle>
                <scale>1.1</scale>
            </LabelStyle>
            <BalloonStyle>
                <text><![CDATA[<h3>$[name]</h3>]]></text>
            </BalloonStyle>
        </Style>
        <StyleMap id='icon-503-FAD199-nodesc'>
            <Pair>
                <key>normal</key>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-FAD199-nodesc-normal</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
            <Pair>
                <key>highlight</key>
                <styleUrl>#icon-503-FAD199-nodesc-highlight</styleUrl>
            </Pair>
        </StyleMap>
    </Document>
</kml>
```

Result:

[image: Markers are still white]

Comment: What does your KML look like?  Possible duplicate of [Google Maps JavaScript API won't display markers from KML exported from My Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323674/google-maps-javascript-api-wont-display-markers-from-kml-exported-from-my-maps)

Comment: It is not a duplicate. I can't see the color but i can see the marker as white.

Comment: What does your KML look like.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: i see this in the kml "http://www.gstatic.com/mapspro/images/stock/503-wht-blank_maps.png"    should i change this manually for each style? Is there a way for this to be as declared in My Maps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read Dr.Molle's answer to the [linked possible duplicate/related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323674/google-maps-javascript-api-wont-display-markers-from-kml-exported-from-my-maps) in my comment:

> According to the documentation `<color/>` isn't supported at all for `<IconStyle/>` and will be ignored

Change the icons to colored icons, like:

http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/red.png
http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/green.png
http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/yellow.png

- [original kml](http://geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160118_coloredMarkersIssue.kml)
- [modified KML with colored icons](http://geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/kml/SO_20160118_colored.kml)

(note it seems to actually be rendering the correct colors for the "google hosted icons" above as someone indicated in the related [issue](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8551#c13))