# KML markers have lost their color (but only in the js api)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Test map here: http://minty.org/gmaps/test2.html

The HTML is valid (as a new user, I'm only allowed 2 links, so I can't include a direct link to the w3 validator)

The KML is valid according to feedvalidator (dot org).

If I load the same KML file as a layer in "Google My Maps", the markers show up as red, green and yellow as intended

https://drive.google.com/open?id=186Bk0V-tNBKdXJ88qQ29YlwaxsY&usp=sharing

But if I try and load the same KML file into a map hosted on my site, they all show up as white

This started happening in the last 24 hours, and was working previously.  I'm not aware of any changes I've made to the KML file that would have caused the colors to suddenly stop working.

The same happens in the latest Firefox & Chrome on a Mac, and up to date iOS on iPad.

Any ideas?

Comment: Related issue in the issue tracker [Issue 8551: Bug: KmlLayer-Placemarks with color different to ffFFFFFF will not be displayed](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=8551)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JavaScript API won't display markers from KML exported from My Maps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32323674/google-maps-javascript-api-wont-display-markers-from-kml-exported-from-my-maps)

Comment: @geocodezip - yup, that is what I did - export some KML from Google My Maps, and then used that to populate a KML layer in the Google Maps Javascript API.  Apparently their KML support is not identical.  Also .. thanks for the reply!

Answer (score 1):

Via the Google Maps Help Forum, Josh258 pointed out my error.

> According to the API documentation <color> for <IconStyle> is not
>   supported. (source:
>   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/kmllayer#supported-elements)

(I was using KML styles that used a white img icon for the marker and KML <color> tags to apply color).

That said, it did magically start working again 24 hours later & is still working now.  So there was just a ~24 hour window during which all the markers went white.

Given it's not a supported feature however, I would conclude it's not an advisable approach.

What is slightly odd is that I took the code from a KML file I exported from "Google My Maps".  However, as Josh258 highlighted, the KML supported by "Google Maps" is not always the same as the KML supported by the Google Maps Javascript API.  Best to check!